# Convert SQL Server syntax to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I got syntax from SQL Server - how to do the conversion to Postgres?

```
declare @localtime varchar(100);
set @localtime = dbo.getdate2();
```

I tried and got this error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "@" LINE 1: declare @localtime varchar(100);

This is my attempt, but it doesn't work:

```
declare v_localtime varchar(100);
v_localtime := dbo.getdate2();
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `current_date` perhaps?

Comment: Where are you doing this, in `plpgsql` possibly? What was the error for the attempted fix? Add information to question.

Comment: Did you check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html

Comment: its a postgres 14 pgadmin

Comment: Using `declare` like this will only work in a `plpgsql` function per [Declarations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html). Outside `plpgsql` [Declare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html) is used to define a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I typically keep dates as dates when using in variables, but the following indeed works when running a script in pgAdmin.

```
set @varname = select to_char(current_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Comment: pgAdmin != Postgres so this does not apply.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I should have clarified that it's a pgScript running against greenplum.

Comment: Again it does not apply as it from pgAdmin 3 which is past EOL used against a fork of Postgres. `set @varname ...` will not be recognized by Postgres.

Comment: Hi exacly, any other solution :(, ihave issiiue:  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@"
LINE 1: set @varname = select to_char(current_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd');